# wordpressのarchive.phpで作成した記事一覧画面のカテゴリボタンを押しても、カテゴリ別の記事一覧ページへ飛ばない問題を解決したい。

Tags: php, wordpress

wordpressで自作テーマを作成しております。
archive.phpで投稿記事一覧ページを作成したのですが、記事のカテゴリリンクをクリックしても、カテゴリ別の投稿記事一覧へ進まない問題を解決したいです。

#### 状況

archive.phpで投稿記事一覧ページを作成済み。
投稿記事のカテゴリをクリックした時に、カテゴリ別一覧へは進まず（URLにはカテゴリが表示されている）カテゴリ関係なく全ての記事が表示される。

#### 望ましい状況

記事一覧ページで表示されている新着記事のカテゴリ（例えば”cat”）をクリックすると、カテゴリをcatで設定している記事だけの一覧を表示させたい。

#### 現在のコード

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>

    <section>
      <div class="diary-h"><h2>日記一覧</h2></div>

    <?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 50 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
   setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="diary-item">
  <div class="diary-img">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('index_thumbnail'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="diary-text">
   <div class="diary-time">
       <?php the_time('Y.m.d') ?>    
   </div>
   <div class="diary-category">
       <?php the_category(',') ?>
   </div>
   <div class="diary-title">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

    </section>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: 「カテゴリ別の投稿記事一覧へ進まない問題」と記述していますが、コードを見るとその類の処理が入っていないように見受けれらます。もしかして「カテゴリ別の投稿データの取得方法がわからない」というのが質問の趣旨ですかね？

Comment: @keitaro_so  返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。「カテゴリ別の投稿データの取得方法」についてですが、[category-〇〇.phpをカテゴリ別に作成し、それぞれで取得していく】とういう方法で解決いたしました！　しかし、現在、「各カテゴリの記事一覧ページにて、記事表示が５個までしかされない」という問題に悩まされております。私の質問一覧に投稿させて頂いているので、お手すきの際に回答いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

category-〇〇.phpをカテゴリ別に作成し、それぞれで取得していく

という方法で解決できました！
閲覧してくださった皆さん、ありがとうございました！！